# Nested Bootstrap Collapse active class Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nested Twitter bootstrap Repeater and I am trying to add active class to the opened collapse using the following script.

```
    function toggleChevronInner(e) {
        console.log('hello');
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find("i.indicator")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down');

        $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading')
            .find("a")
            .toggleClass('active inactive');
    }
    $('#accordionInner').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevronInner);
    $('#accordionInner').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevronInner);
    function toggleChevronMain(e) {
        console.log('hi');
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find("span.indicator")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-top glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
        $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading')
            .find("a")
            .toggleClass('active inactive');
    }
    $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevronMain);
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevronMain);
```

However, I saw a strange issue. When I am expanding the main Accordion i.e. `#accordion`, the function `toggleChevronInner` is also being called.

Why the behavior like this even after the IDs are different and how can it be fixed?

You can see it in action at http://jsbin.com/kagowi/1/edit?js,console,output . For Commodities it has nested collapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's happening is because of the way that events propagate.

Check the answer I gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544958/event-handlers-and-listeners-event-bubbling-and-event-capturing/32545369).

Because #accordionInner is a child of #accordion - AND because they're both listening for the same event, they'll both respond to it.

To fix it, do this:

```
function toggleChevronInner(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```