# Stop event firing by child elements (without having access to event handler)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Let's suppose we have a `<div>` and some nested elements:

```
<div id="outer">
  <!-- some code goes here ---> 
  <div id="inner">
    <!-- some code goes here ---> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Some listener (let's call it `onOuterClicked`) is bound to `#outer` and is captured by `#inner`, which is not what I want. The point is that:

- I can't alter `onOuterClicked` (I just have no access to it)
- I want `#inner` to call `onInnerClicked` by click
- I don't want `#inner` to call `onOuterClicked` by click
- `#inner` may be added or deleted later

So if I just bind `onInnerClicked` listener to `#inner` by jQuery `.on`, it will anyway call `onOuterClicked`. How can I avoid it?

Sorry if it's a duplicate question, but all answers I found here are about changing body of `onOuterClicked` which is not something I can do.

Comment: wrap the call to outer event listener, `outer.addEventListener("click",function(evt){ evt.stopPropagation(); onOuterClicked(evt)},false);`

Comment: Needs to be a HELL of a reason for "can't" in this situation.  Read my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544958/event-handlers-and-listeners-event-bubbling-and-event-capturing/) to get a better understanding of event propagation - and use the example of stopPropagation() Rejith has given you below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child anchor is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#inner',function(event){
    if($(event.target).closest('#inner').length == 0 ){
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        onInnerClicked(); 
    }
});
```